# Is there any software like mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate

I m currently learning hibernate but in the course he is using mysql workbench which didn't work form me i've tried thousand solution, so i installed the postgresql i m asking is there any software similar mysql workbench or even better and thanks.

Comment: Perhaps pgAdmin.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several of varying quality](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients). The most commonly used client—also most likely to support all of PostgreSQL's features—is [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/). It's comprehensive from a PostgreSQL feature standpoint, but lacks the user interface polish of MySQL Workbench.

A tool that has the feature set but also includes more a user-centric UI is [pgModeler](https://pgmodeler.io/) by Raphael A. Silva. It's free if you compile the source yourself. Alternatively you can download a compiled binary for a fee.

If all you're looking for is a way to list tables/views and run ad hoc queries, you can download extensions to your favorite IDE, eg. VS Code. This has the advantage of allowing you to highlight queries in your editor and run them without needing to jump to another tool.